# Textbox in Winforms/C++ behaves in mystic ways

Tags: c++, winforms, system, stdstring

I have several texboxes, and when I enter any symbols in some of them, it gives me error - that the string is in wrong format. What's more weird, when I enter some data to another textbox plus enter symbols in the mentioned one, it works ok. Plus, in another form everything is almost the same and works fine. What can be wrong about what I'm doing?
So, I have a few textboxex: I enter book's id in box2, enter book's name in box 1. When I fill both boxex, it's ok, but when I only enter anything in box one(with book's name) - it gives me error. I tried to create another form from scratch and it gives the very same error.
Anyway, when I press button, I go to this code, which creates an error:
(Btw, I understand, I could use System::String instead of std::string, but for the purposes of this particular project I still need std::string, hope you understand me)
Code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        std::string name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(textBox1->Text);
        std::string tmpIdBook = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(textBox2->Text);
        int idBook;
        if (1) { //I'll check if boxex aren't empty later
            idBook = -1;//if id == -1, my method in books.findInAll() ignores it and
            //searches the book only by its name
            if (isNumeric_(tmpIdBook)) { //my function that checks if it's numeric
                idBook = System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
            }
            auto found = books->findInAll(name, idBook, -1, -1); //get vector with books I found
            //No need to read further, error originates before what's lower. That's only a test version, what I wrote lower, to see if it works
            std::string res;
            res = "Found books:";
            System::String^ Str;
            for (auto el : found) {
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Book's name: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = el->getName();
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Book's Id: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = std::to_string(el->getBookId());
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Author's Id: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = std::to_string(el->getAuthorId());
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Location: Rack: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = std::to_string(el->getBookLocation().getRack());
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Shelf: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = std::to_string(el->getBookLocation().getShelf());
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
                res = "Section: ";
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data());
                res = std::to_string(el->getBookLocation().getSection());
                Str = Str + gcnew String(res.data()) + Environment::NewLine;
            }
            textBox3->Text = Str;
            textBox1->Text = L"";
            textBox2->Text = L"";
            
        }
        else {
            MessageBox::Show(this, "Invalid data input, try again");
            textBox1->Text = L"";
            textBox2->Text = L"";
        
        }
    }
```

So, when I enter book1 to box1 and 0 to box2< i get in box three my book with name book1 and id == 0, but when I only enter book1 in box1, it's an error. I have no idea what's the problem

Comment: Don't know the answer, love the title.

Comment: Is your `isNumeric_()` function doing something like `return tmpIdBook.length() && std::all_of(tmpIdBook.begin(), tmpIdBook.end(), ::isdigit);`? I.e., are you checking the length of the string? `System::Convert::ToInt32()` throws if the string is empty -- Why haven't you posted the exception you're receiving?

Comment: Use white line both in question and in code to improve clarity. By the way, you should use `StringBuilder` if you build a string like you do. Finally, by using a debugger, you could probably find the source of the problem in less than 5 seconds. Ensure that the debugger stop on exceptions... By the way, using `int.TryParse` might be more appropriate here...

Comment: The isNumeric_() function is broken, it ignores an empty string.  Get rid of it, use int::TryParse() instead.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! I finally managed to use a debugger with forms and found a few mistakes, and they, as you were right, were that I tried to convert an empty string to an int. I fixed both the is_Numeric function and checks for input validity. Thank you for a helpful hand!